# How do I set INVERT_MATCHING on a ZeroMQ PUB socket with PyZMQ?

Tags: zeromq, distributed-system, pyzmq

I'm working with PyZMQ 16.0.4 backed by ZeroMQ 4.1.6 and trying to get a better sense of the socket option **`INVERT_MATCHING`**.

I've tried the following in a repl:

```
>>> import zmq
>>> context = zmq.Context.instance()
>>> pubsock = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
>>> pubsock.INVERT_MATCHING = 1
```

The last line gives me an error

> `AttributeError: Socket has no such option: INVERT_MATCHING`.

Am I just seeing a bug in PyZMQ?

Or do I need to do something different to set this option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ZeroMQ **`PUB`**-sockets have only supported invert matching since [version 4.2](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-setsockopt#toc22).  You need to update your ZeroMQ.

Note that PyZMQ bundles a precompiled ZeroMQ 4.1.6.  So depending on how you installed PyZMQ you may not actually be using your system's ZeroMQ.

Try the following to reinstall PyZMQ and force recompilation of the ZeroMQ backend.

```
$ pip install pyzmq --ignore-installed --no-use-wheel
```

Answer (score -1):

### Let's go: using `.setsockopt()`

```
print( "ZeroMQ version ought be 4.2+ ... Hope it is... " )
print( zmq.version() )
print( pubsock.setsockopt.__doc__ )
pass;  pubsock.setsockopt( zmq.INVERT_MATCHING, 1 )
```

---

### Plus best re-read the documentation:

> Reverses the filtering behavior of **`PUB-SUB`** sockets, when set to 1.
>
> On **`PUB`** and **`XPUB`** sockets, this causes messages to be sent to all connected sockets except those subscribed to a prefix that matches the message. On **`SUB`** sockets, this causes only incoming messages that do not match any of the socket's subscriptions to be received by the user.  
>   **Whenever `ZMQ_INVERT_MATCHING` is set to 1 on a `PUB` socket, all `SUB` sockets connecting to it must also have the option set to 1. Failure to do so will have the `SUB` sockets reject everything the `PUB` socket sends them**.
> **`XSUB`** sockets do not need to do this because they do not filter incoming messages.

Comment: !!!  I installed ZMQ 4.2.3 with homebrew, but zmq.version() returns 40106 (4.1.6).  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Oh yeah, I’m just checking to make sure it does indeed solve my problem first. I haven’t yet figured out why / how to solve the wrong ZeroMQ version yet

Comment: With all due respect, that is another subject / activity, not related with the root-cause analysis + self-diagnostic steps + API-documentation reminder delivered, is it?

Comment: I can't accept the answer until I confirm it solves the problem.  If you said "Try moving your laptop around" I would treat it the same way ... I would try it and see if that fixes the issue, then accept it if so.  Have some patience.

Comment: "***Try moving your laptop around***" - serious? Who said this? Do as you feel. **But even if you never manage to install the 4.2 API / DLL, the answer is both correct & complete, so adding more and more if-s and when-s is** possible, but **not related to the original question, is it?**

Comment: You assert it's correct and complete.  I'm glad you're confident.  But ultimately, that's my decision to make, because it's my question.  I have no idea right now if it's correct, much less complete.  Have a good day